# Concurrency in C

Tags: c, http, concurrency, webserver, c99

I want to make a simple web server in C that handles requests concurrently. So far I got the following code that forks the process and executes the request_handle in the child process. (That is at least what I aim to have) but still, executing a request blocks the cycle and until the first request is completed, the second request is not accepted. What should I fix to allow the web server to handle requests concurrently?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "request.h"
#include "io_helper.h"

char default_root[] = ".";

//
// ./wserver [-p <portnum>] [-t threads] [-b buffers] 
// 
// e.g.
// ./wserver -p 2022 -t 5 -b 10
// 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c;
    char *root_dir = default_root;
    int port = 10000;
    int threads = 2;
    int buffer_size = 5;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "p:t:b:")) != -1)
        switch (c) {
            case 'p':
                port = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 't':
                threads = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'b':
                buffer_size = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./wserver [-p <portnum>] [-t threads] [-b buffers] \n");
                exit(1);
            }



    printf("Server running on port: %d, threads: %d, buffer: %d\n", port, threads, buffer_size);

    // run out of this directory
    chdir_or_die(root_dir);

    // now, get to work
    int listen_fd = open_listen_fd_or_die(port);
    while (1) {
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        int client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        int conn_fd = accept(listen_fd, (sockaddr_t *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *) &client_len);

        pid_t child_pid;
        child_pid = fork();

        if (child_pid == 0) {
            close(listen_fd);
            request_handle(conn_fd);
            close(conn_fd);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            close(conn_fd);
        }
    }
    close(listen_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use threads, not processes for this

Comment: Regardless of whether you use `fork` or `pthread_create` to start the handler task for the request, the main thread/process has to "reap" the child when completed (using a nonblocking call). This is either `waitpid(0,...,WNOHANG)` or `pthread_tryjoin_np`. Actually, using `fork` and `waitpid` seems to be cleaner.

Comment: Pico HTTPD, a very simple HTTP server for Unix, using fork().  https://gist.github.com/laobubu/d6d0e9beb934b60b2e552c2d03e1409e or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669474/multiclient-server-using-fork or https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2010/04/15/very-simple-http-server-writen-in-c/

Comment: Non blocking I/o and `poll()`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the assignment requires me to use fork

Comment: You are missing too much context for anyone to help much.   Your pattern is fine; classic really; but does listen_or_die really work?